# Pagedlist for asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, pagedlist

In MVC 5 (.Net Framework 4.6) i used PagedList.Mvc with following solutions:

1. It separates query into pages and gets results for needed page (not all query results).
2. It used HtmlHelper to render  group of buttons with needed filter!

   3. I could customize numbers of pager buttons to display (if get large resultset).

In asp.net core 2.0 documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/sort-filter-page i can't find 2 and 3 solutions.
Does anyone know better approach?

Comment: https://www.cloudscribe.com/docs/cloudscribe-web-pagination

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tried PagedList from https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList it worked!

Comment: The original PagedList has been abandoned for quite some time now. Even with MVC 5, you should have been using X.PagedList, which is a fork of the original library that is being maintained.

Comment: Is there a `@Html.PagedListPager` Razor helper in X.PagedList?

Comment: Yes , https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/blob/master/examples/X.PagedList.Mvc.Example/Views/TraditionalPaging/Index.cshtml

Answer (score 1):

I used `X.PagedList` this link was very helpful

https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/README.markdown#example